# Multiple selection in edit form shows more than one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that has nested attributes.

The form is about products and a product has many locations. I am trying to list the locations in a dropdown manner using `collection_select` but it shows more than one time (twice in fact). What am I doing wrong?

Relevant part of the form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :stocks do |ff| %>
    <div class="input-field  margin-top x-4">
      <%= collection_select :product, :location_ids, Location.all, :id, :structured_location , {:prompt => "Please Select Locations for Product"}, {multiple: true} %>
      <%= f.label :locations %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working in a similar project.

Make sure that in your `parent`'s controller, you are permitting the `:id` of the `child` model, something as following:

`params.require(:parent).permit(children_attributes: [:id, :child_first_attribute, ...])`

Hope this helps!